# Fade one image into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be a simple question.  When I press a button, I'd like to fade out one image and fade in a new one.  I have a button binded to this function:

```
function changeBackground() {
var background = document.getElementById("background");
var h_background = document.getElementById("background_hidden")

$('#background').fadeOut('slow', function() {$('#background_hidden').fadeIn('slow')});
}
```

In the CSS, h_background has a display: none; attribute.  With this function as it is, the current image will fade out and the other one will display but it does not fade in - it shows up suddenly.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Added a jsfiddle, but it currently does not work - trying to figure out why.
http://jsfiddle.net/qrCjA/8/

Comment: Would it mess things up if you just set the opacity of h_background to 0? I've heard there's issues with jQuery fading in elements with display: none.

Comment: There is no problem in your code. when are you calling changeBackground function?

Comment: no reason shouldn't work based on code shown unless using tables or some other code is in effect. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: @Sushil I'm calling it when I click on a button on the page.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: Just curious, since you're using jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById("background");` instead of `$('#background')`?

Comment: @j08691 I just learned jquery/javascript recently and using the .getElementById was the way it was taught. Jquery is obviously much better though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your fiddle and cleaned the code a little: http://jsfiddle.net/4FzqA/.

After looking between my cleaned version and your original, the only difference was that the fiddle was set to "onDomReady" on mine, when yours is set to "onLoad".

Otherwise, the code should have been functional.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = $("#fade_out").click(changeBackground);
}

function changeBackground() {
    $('#background').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#background_hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```

**Edit**: It looks like the window.onload was conflicting with the onLoad in the original fiddle, since the original fiddle didn't work for me.  When I changed window.load to document ready, all was well, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $("#fade_out").click(changeBackground);
});
```

**Another edit**: If the image is large, you could try waiting for it to load, but keep in mind that the load won't trigger if pulled from cache:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var img = new Image();
   $(img)
      .hide()
      .load(function(){
         $("body").append(this);
         $(this).fadeIn(3000);
      })
      .attr("src", "files/originals/01.jpg");
});
```

Taken from: [Fading in large images in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979552/fading-in-large-images-in-chrome).

**Another edit:** From the sounds of it, you might be correct in guessing that it is an issue with the image size.  I updated my original fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4FzqA/7/) with the new images and the load.  Notice that the image is loaded each time which isn't very efficient.  But it will give you an idea.  Below is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $("#fade_out").click(changeBackground);
});

function changeBackground() {
    $('#background').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#background_hidden')
            .attr('src', 'http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8633/daynightm.jpg?' + (new Date()).getTime())
            .load(function () { 
                $(this).fadeIn('slow'); 
            });  
    });
}
```

Comment: In this case onload and ondomready are equivalent so you provided non real solution here. Plus the fiddle the OP created works.

Comment: Is it possible something is wrong with my jQuery/javascript?  I've set up the exact situation but my jsfiddle and normal javascript still isn't working.  The image will fade out and the other image will come in instantly instead of fading in.

Comment: Alright ... here's what's weird.  I changed the images to the cat and dog used in my jsfiddle example.  It works fine with those images...is it possible for an image to be too big and to not be able to fade in properly?

Comment: @j08691 - Odd because the original fiddle didn't work for me.

Comment: @joshft91 - See my edit, when I changed to document ready, your original fiddle worked like expected.

Comment: @joshft91 - I haven't encountered an issue with fading and image size, but I wouldn't be too surprised.  Is there a way to use those images in fiddle for testing?

Comment: @joshft91 - You could try waiting for image to load (see edit).

Comment: Here are the two images I was using. The first is the 'default' one
http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/1460/daysky.jpg
The second one is the one I was having issues with:
http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/8633/daynightm.jpg

Comment: This jsfiddle is showing the behavior I was experiencing.
http://jsfiddle.net/yXDzE/

Comment: @joshft91 - You might be correct in guessing that it is an image size issue.  I linked an updated fiddle and added some new code for loading the image.  The tricky part is that the example will load the image each time (using date) which isn't very efficient.

Comment: I tried to add a couple lines to make it so that I can click the button multiple times and have it fade to a new background every time the button is clicked ... I must be missing something.  This is unrelated to the original post, but thought it deserved to go here anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/8F3gD/

Comment: @joshft91 - From what I could tell in the jsfiddle, you were trying to cycle between the two images.  See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huvAc/.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to cycle that way, but your way looks more effective.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#fade_out").click(function(){
    changeBackground();
});

function changeBackground() {
    var background = document.getElementById("background");
    var h_background = document.getElementById("background_hidden")

    $('#background').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#background_hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
​
```

It works in this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4FzqA/1/